# SharePoint Infrastructure Update Authentication Issues

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, ntlm, infrastructure

I've got a SharePoint MOSS 2007 development setup on to which I installed the WSS infrastructure update.  Now, whenever I try to access any site collection in my SharePoint farm using IE7 I get a username and password prompt.  I enter valid credentials for my Site Collection admin account and I see the box again.  This happens three times then after the third time I just see a blank page.

When I access the system through FireFox 3.0 I get the username and password screen but after putting the credentials in the first time, the site runs as normal.

I presume this is because IE is using NTLM whereas Firefox is using basic authentication, but I'm not sure how to resolve the issue.

Has anyone else experienced this or can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance
 - Russell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer to this now.  It was all to do with this issue...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Before the infrastructure update just entering the FQDN (e.g. intranet.domain.local) for BackConnectionHostNames entry in Method one worked fine.  After the infrastructure update I added just the hostname (e.g. intranet) to the BackConnectionHostNames entry and this fixed the issue! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had to turn off IE ESC to get this to stop. For some reason, it worked on all servers except one in our farm. Who knows. Hope this helps you get started.

Comment: I turned off IE ESC and it didnt help :-(

I'm now running with basic authentication and it works ok, but I still want to know how to fix it so I can use NTLM again.  Anyone got any more suggestions?